# Displaying specific node type in a page programmatically

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, hooks

I am a drupal 8 developer, who just needed to migrate drupal 6 site to drupal 7. I migrated all the content and database successfully, but some node pages displays header, footer but it doesn't display the content which has bunch of nodes of node type FAQ. I have page--faq.tpl.php in template and node--faq.tpl.php. This is what I see when I go to /faq page:

[image]

I am not even able to see what is in my $variables array when I hook node via:

```
function joycone_preprocess_node(&$variables)
{
    kpr($variables);
}
```

I should at least see whats in $variables when I go to /faq page. But it doesnt even print kpr.

I wanna display FAQ nodes(node type is FAQ) where it says "The requested page '/faq' could not be found.". Here is my question:

Do I need to use some sort of template hook so drupal 7 theme get that dynamically? Because I have product and promotion pages that I wanna display product and promotion nodes at /products and /promotions page.

I am not sure if Drupal 7 gets what nodes will be displayed at what page automatically via template naming. If I need to use preprocess hook what will it be?

Or do I need to create individual modules for each page and pass nodes to template like that?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If the name of your content type is faq the templates should work. But do you really have a page named /faq? This is another different thing go to check if this page really exists.

Comment: Yes I do have /faq page. Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: The View is missing? What is /faq?

Comment: @Kevin /faq is the url that I wanna display all faq nodes. I am not using view module, I am trying to display faq nodes programmatically.

Comment: The question is misleading then.... there’s no code above pertaining to creating your own menu item with page callback in order to do it. Views would have it in two minutes. It can be done programmatically too but the original question is asking something else.

Comment: @Kevin I have added some more details.

Comment: There’s no such thing as “/faq” though if you haven’t made a menu item or View. You originally stated you want to have a page at /faq that lists nodes, which is the use case for Views. Or you have to code it all up in a module too.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for your quick response and sorry for my late response, so in drupal 6 site, doesn't have any /faq page but it has a menu item FAQs. When I inspected to that menu item, i have realized that "PATH" of the menu item is something like this "nodeorder/term/1". 

So I have tried add the same menu item with same title and path for the site which is now upgraded to drupal 7, I throws:

"The path 'nodeorder/term/1' is either invalid or you do not have access to it."

I am really stuck with it. I don't know if I need to create a new question related to this situation.